# Regex pattern for a special identifier that exclude matches with digits only

Tags: regex

I'm searching for a regex pattern that finds the following items:

Start, Stop, Stop1, 1Hz, E1.1, A3.2, Emergeny_Stop

Minimum 1 character and maximal 24 characters.
My solution is:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z_.]{1,24}
```

Now I search for a modification that excludes items that consist of only digits:

I want to ignore items like:

11,222, 5.2, etc

Finally, I want to ignore items that start with:
0x
16#

Is there a regex pro who can help me?
Thanks a lot.

P.S. Here is a nice test environment:
https://regex101.com/

Comment: Which flavour of regex?

Comment: `5.2` does not consist of only digits. It would be best to first extract all matches and then filter them out with a simple `^\d+(?:\.\d+)*$` pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/m5Y6SW/2)

```
^(?!0x)(?=.*?[a-z])[\w.]{1,24}$
```

Alternatively, if your regex engine supports Unicode classes, you can use:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/m5Y6SW/4)

```
^(?!0x)(?=.*?\p{L})[\p{L}\p{N}_.]{1,24}$
```

If you only want to negate `0x` but you want to include `0X`, you can use the following (assuming your regex engine supports inline modifiers):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/m5Y6SW/3)

```
^(?!0x)(?i)(?=.*?[a-z])[\w.]{1,24}$
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
Start
Stop
Stop1
1Hz
E1.1
A3.2
Emergeny_Stop

11
222
5.2
0x123
16#abc123
```

#### Output

Below result includes matches only.

```
Start
Stop
Stop1
1Hz
E1.1
A3.2
Emergeny_Stop
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?!0x)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match `0x`
- `(?=.*?[a-z])` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows includes a letter (notice the case-insensitive `i` flag is enabled, thus this also searches uppercase variants)
- `[\w.]{1,24}` Match any character present in the set (word characters or dot) between 1 and 24 times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: @Matt you're very welcome! Btw `\w` is the *same* as `a-zA-Z0-9_`. (I use *same* liberally here as there are sometimes differences when it comes to regex engines and how they support Unicode characters)